# AngularJS: multi dimensional array $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Here's the scenario

I have this markup and I want to loop this based on the $scope of arrays that was returned by the API

```
<div class="car-group" ng-repeat="p in photos">
    <input type="text" name="product_description" id="product_description" class="form-control product_description" ng-model="p.product_description">

    <div class="car-photos">
        <input type="text" name="photo_label" class="form-control photo label" ng-model="p.photo_label">
        <input type="text" name="photo_label" class="form-control photo label" ng-model="p.image_data">
    </div>  
</div>
```

**JSON**

```
$scope.photos = [
                  [
                       {"photo_label":"Cover","image_data":"cover.jpg"},
                       {"product_description":"Car Cover"}
                  ],

                  [
                       {"photo_label":"Inside","image_data":"inside.jpg"},
                       {"photo_label":"Rear","image_data":"rear.jpg"},
                       {"product_description":"Car View"}
                  ]
               ]
```

here's an illustration of what I want to do

[image]

The number of photos depends on the JSON response from the server.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the structure of the json?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about how the number of images is deciding the width of each image box ?

Comment: @ndoes.. change the json structure?? what do you mean? sorry I'm confused..

Comment: The objects contain different properties. Looping would be possible, but there would be a bunch of conditional statements in your view. Structuring the JSON [like this](https://jsonblob.com/c79cc3db-c8ee-11e6-b16a-c9fe80d96e02) would make more sense imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your *json object* into this format:

```
[
  {
    "images": [
      {
        "photo_label": "Cover",
        "image_data": "cover.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "product_description": "Car Cover"
  },
  {
    "images": [
      {
        "photo_label": "Inside",
        "image_data": "inside.jpg"
      },
      {
        "photo_label": "Rear",
        "image_data": "rear.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "product_description": "Car View"
  }
]
```

for easier *data binding* with your markup using an *ng-repeat* inside an *ng-repeat*.

See demo below:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.photos = [
    [{
      "photo_label": "Cover",
      "image_data": "cover.jpg"
    }, {
      "product_description": "Car Cover"
    }],
    [{
      "photo_label": "Inside",
      "image_data": "inside.jpg"
    }, {
      "photo_label": "Rear",
      "image_data": "rear.jpg"
    }, {
      "product_description": "Car View"
    }]
  ].reduce(function(p, c) {
    let obj = {};
    c.forEach(function(e) {
      if (e['product_description']) {
        obj['product_description'] = e['product_description'];
      } else {
        obj['images'] = obj['images'] || [];
        obj['images'].push({
          "photo_label": e['photo_label'],
          "image_data": e['image_data']
        });
      }
    });
    p.push(obj);
    return p;
  }, []);

  // console.log($scope.photos);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div class="car-group" ng-repeat="p in photos">
    <input type="text" name="product_description" id="product_description" class="form-control product_description" ng-model="p.product_description">

    <div class="car-photos" ng-repeat="img in p.images">
      <input type="text" name="photo_label" class="form-control photo label" ng-model="img.photo_label">
      <input type="text" name="photo_label" class="form-control photo label" ng-model="img.image_data">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May look a bit heavy-handed - but maybe something like this?

```
<div class="car-group" ng-repeat="p in photos">
    <div ng-repeat="elt in p | filter: myDesc">
        <input type="text" name="product_description" id="product_description" class="form-control product_description" ng-model="elt.product_description">
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="elt in p | filter: myImage">
        <div class="car-photos">
            <input type="text" name="photo_label" class="form-control photo label" ng-model="elt.photo_label">
            <input type="text" name="photo_label" class="form-control photo label" ng-model="elt.image_data">
        </div>  
    </div>
```

where

```
$scope.myDesc = function(elt){
    if (elt.product_description){
        return true;
    } else{
        return;
    }
};

$scope.myImage = function(elt){
    if (elt.photo_label || elt.image_data){
        return true;
    } else{
        return;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all we have here quite wrong data structure, I assume that it can not be change, so I will show solution with converting this structure to some more accurate. Why this structure is wrong:

- single element array have dynamic count of elements
- single element is array of object with different type - and array are structure used to store elements of the same type. Currently we have in the same array photo object and product property object.

To fix it we need to separate product props from photos, my proposition is to convert single element array to object:

```
{
"photos": [
  {
    "photo_label": "Inside",
    "image_data": "inside.jpg"
  },
  {
    "photo_label": "Rear",
    "image_data": "rear.jpg"
  }
],
"product_description": "Car View"
}
```

We can think that this object represent product properties and photos are one of them. I think also products is better way to name this, because photos are just product props.

Ok, so I have prepared working solution with converting function underneath.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("controller", function($scope){

  //server structure
  var products = [
    [
      {"photo_label":"Cover","image_data":"cover.jpg"},
      {"product_description":"Car Cover"}
    ],
    [
      {"photo_label":"Inside","image_data":"inside.jpg"},
      {"photo_label":"Rear","image_data":"rear.jpg"},
      {"product_description":"Car View"}
    ]
  ];
  
  //function coverting structure to better one
  function _convertToProperStructure(arr){
    
    return arr.map(function(el){
      
      var properEl={ 'photos': [] };
      
      //last element is description so without it
      for ( var i=0; i< el.length-1; i++ ){
        
        properEl.photos.push(el[i]);//add photo
        
      }
      
      //set description
      properEl.product_description = el[el.length-1].product_description;
      
      return properEl;
    });
    
  };
  
  //convert to proper structure
  $scope.products=_convertToProperStructure(products);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
<div  class="car-group" ng-repeat="p in products">
    <input type="text" name="product_description" id="product_description" class="form-control product_description" ng-model="p.product_description">

    <div class="car-photos" ng-repeat="p in p.photos">
        <input type="text" name="photo_label" class="form-control photo label" ng-model="p.photo_label">
        <input type="text" name="photo_label" class="form-control photo label" ng-model="p.image_data">
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KimCarlo awesome! I something is not clear - just ask.

Answer (score 0):

[Here I added Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xk75Ppf3lSBXZWNn4XHJ?p=preview)

```
Hi
```

I changed your json object into this format:

```
$scope.photos = [
                      {"product_description":"Car Cover",
                        "images":
                        [
                             {"photo_label":"Cover","image_data":"cover.jpg"}

                        ]},


                            {"product_description":"Car View",
                        "images":
                            [
                             {"photo_label":"Inside","image_data":"inside.jpg"},
                             {"photo_label":"Rear","image_data":"rear.jpg"}
                        ]}

                     ]
```